# Write non-differential equation as a smooth optimization problem

Tags: optimization, smooth-functions

Edit: the previous title was "Re-writing a function so it becomes differentiable"- I see now that this is not exactly possible. The actual question is to "show that this (problem below) can be written as a smooth constrained optimization function". I am still unsure of how to do this.

I have an optimization question with a non-differentiable function:
$$ f(x) = \max(x^2, x)$$
The objective function is to minimise $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have re-written $f(x)$ as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \mbox{for}\; x \in [0,1] \\
x^2 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Is this now a smooth function? I don't feel like I've changed the function so how could it be smooth?

Comment: You are right twice: you haven't changed it and it did not become smooth.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I checked again and it's actually for x in R

Comment: Your title is confusing. A function is either differentiable or it is not, and rewriting it can’t change that. In any event, you seem to be wanting to minimize a function, not make it differentiable.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks lol that makes sense. I'm not really familiar with smooth functions, what requirements does f need to satisfy to become smooth?

Comment: Your function $f$ is not smooth, since it is not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: This function is differentiable everywhere except $x=0$ or $x=1.$ So to find the minimum, first check where the derivatives exist and are zero (which is nowhere,) then find the minimum of $f(0)$ and $f(1).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok maybe I will have to edit the wording. The exact question was "Show that this can be written as a smooth constrained optimization problem". I thought that I would have to re-write the objective function to be smooth. Maybe I need to write it as two separate problems?

Comment: @Barok Since the function is non-negative, you can instead minimize $g(f(x))$ for any increasing $g$ on $\mathbb R^{\geq0}.$ You might be able to find a clever $g$  which makes $g(f(x))$ smooth. But that isn’t rewriting $f,$ but rather, replacing $f.$

Comment: For example, $g(x)=\min(x,x^2).$